# Problem with return view on android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a spinner in fragment_home xml that is connected to the HomeFragment class this spinner is filling the listview but the problem is with another spinner in another xml that has no class and it is not filling the listview
i think the problem is return

I need return fragmentview and fragmentview2

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View fragmentView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_add_post,container,false);
    popup_filter = fragmentView2.findViewById(R.id.sniperadd);
    // Trazendo o layout para esse fragmento
    View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    filtrarPost = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.filtrarSpinner);
    //Instanciando um RecyclerView(Usado para Fazer uma lista)
    postRecyclerView  = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.postRV);
    //Usado para gerenciar o Layout usado no fragmentHome
    postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    //Obter tamanhos do RecyclerView para nao ocorrer problemas
    postRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //Pegando a referencia qual banco vai ser usado no caso vai pegar o Posts
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Posts");
            //PEGANDO TODOS OS POSTS
            filtertodos = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
    //SELECIONANDO PELO Nome
    filterpost1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts")
            .orderByChild("title")
            .equalTo("Post1");
    filterpost2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts")
            .orderByChild("title")
            .equalTo("Post2");
    //SELECIONANDO POR ID
    filterid = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("artistas")
            .orderByChild("artistaId")
            .equalTo("-LnOwoqaH-yy7j6vw9-r");
    //LIMITANDO A QUANTIDADE
    filterlimite = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("artistas").limitToFirst(2);
    //BUSCANDO POR IDADE < 30
    filteridade = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("artistas")
            .orderByChild("idade")
            .endAt(29);
    //BUSCANDO POR NOME COMEÇA A
    filtername = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("artistas")
            .orderByChild("artistaNome")
            .startAt("A")
            .endAt("A\uf8ff");
    return fragmentView;
}
```

Comment: Can you just elaborate your problem?

Comment: i can send imgur link for you see ?

Comment: Yaa sure bud. Send it

Comment: this is xml with spinner with class
https://i.imgur.com/voa5Eef.jpeg
this is xml with spinner with out class
https://i.imgur.com/0WFPIBC.jpeg
this is view i instancied spinner and query for view list,filtrarpost is work and popup_filter not work
https://i.imgur.com/ggP5l6S.jpeg
this is function for query spinner with i put filtrarPost is work but i need the other spinner work
https://i.imgur.com/WwSVL4M.jpeg
is work with filtraraPost
https://i.imgur.com/jqTMxOt.jpeg
now this is function with the other spinner
https://i.imgur.com/fTwuGAq.jpeg
n work
https://i.imgur.com/rTTbGR9.jpeg

Comment: in the code above you can see that fragmentview2 is not returning